# How can I trigger a function when one of my state changes?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When ever someone clicks on a sidemenu button, the state in my component changes( like from "New York Knicks" to "Boston Celtics"). In componentDidMount, I have

```
componentDidMount() {
        TeamStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
        var knicksRef = new Firebase(this.props.baseUrl + this.state.name + "/results");

        this.bindAsArray(knicksRef, 'articles');

    }
```

Which basically takes an array from the states category and binds it as an array to "articles". However, I was hoping that every time the state changes, it would pull from a different category and bind that to articles instead. How can I make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ComponentDidMount` [as said in the doc](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) will only be called once.

You want to perform an action when the state change. I guess you're calling `setState()` in your `_onChange` method, so just wrap your logic into another method and call it from `_onChange` and `componentDidMount` methods.

Note that you could also put this logic inside the `componentDidUpdate` which is called whenever the component, well, did just update itself when the state has changed. But it will not be called on the first render.

So, finally, I think you should do something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    TeamStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    this._updateKnickRef();
}

_onChange() {
    //update state here
    this._updateKnicksRef();
}

_updateKnicksRef() {
    var knicksRef = new Firebase(this.props.baseUrl + this.state.name + "/results");

    this.bindAsArray(knicksRef, 'articles');
}
```